# Java 7 fails to create a file on Win7 with a 230-character path

Tags: java, windows, fileoutputstream

I had some new code using the commons-io FileUtils.openOutputStream(File) method, for a file that doesn't exist at the point of the call.  This was failing with a "FileNotFoundException".  I first thought this was a bug in commons-io, but then I realized that it's just calling "new FileOutputStream(file, append)", which is also supposed to create the file if it doesn't exist.

I then added code right before my call to FileUtils.openOutputStream(File) like the following:

```
            if (!file.exists()) {
            logger.info("Parent file exists: " + file.getParentFile().exists());
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error("Creating file failed", ex);
            }
        }
```

This prints "true" for the parent file, and then "java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified".  I googled for this situation, and some people were hitting this if they went past the supposed 260 character limit for a file path on Windows.  I thought that might be relevant, but my file path is only 230 characters long.

I also tried an experiment of trying to "touch" the same file path in my Cygwin bash shell, and it had no trouble doing that.

**Update**:

So I took the partial advice of trying to use Paths & Files to do this instead of just "File".  My incoming parameter is a "File", so I can't do anything about that.  I added the following code:

```
        try {
            Path    path    = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()).toAbsolutePath();
            if (!Files.exists(path.getParent())) {
                Files.createDirectories(path);
            }
            file    = Files.createFile(path).toFile();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Failed to create file");
        }
```

What's curious is that this doesn't give me a better error message.  In fact, it doesn't give me any error message, because it doesn't fail.  It appears that NIO is taking a very different path to creating the file than the regular File object.

**Update**:

What is now working fine is the following:

```
        file    = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()).toAbsolutePath().toFile();
        try {
            Path    path    = file.toPath();
            if (!Files.exists(path.getParent())) {
                Files.createDirectories(path);
            }
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file    = Files.createFile(path).toFile();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Failed to create file");
        }
```

What's curious is that I should be able to remove that first line, which is essentially converting a relative path to an absolute path.  My test run creates 50 or so files in the process.  I tried commenting out that line and then clearing out my output tree and running the test.  It got the following exception attempting to create the first file:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: build\gen1\org\opendaylight\yang\gen\v1\urn\opendaylight\params\xml\ns\yang\pcep\types\rev131005\vs\tlv\vs\tlv\VendorPayload.java
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
```

What the heck?

Also note that I never did remove the older code that uses "File.createNewFile()", I just put the "Files" code before that, and the old code checks for "!file.exists()", so theoretically the old code would only execute if the new code somehow didn't create the file.  On this first file, since the NIO creation failed, the file still didn't exist, and it went through the old creation code, which SUCCEEDED.

And even stranger, I let the test case run to the next file, and that failed in the NEW code with:

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: build\gen1\org\opendaylight\yang\gen\v1\urn\opendaylight\params\xml\ns\yang\pcep\types\rev131005\vs\tlv\VsTlv.java
```

Note that the only way that block could have gotten that exception is if it executed the "Files.createFile(path).toFile()" line, and the only way it could have gotten to that line is if "!file.exists()" was TRUE, which means that the file did not exist.  my brain is starting to melt.  Also note that while I'm sitting at this breakpoint, I examined the file system, and that file does not exist.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the full string of that path?

Comment: It is "build/gen1/org/opendaylight/yang/gen/v1/urn/opendaylight/params/xml/ns/yang/network/topology/unix/rev131222/network/topology/topology/node/path/computation/client/reported/lsp/lsp/tlvs/vs/tlv/vendor/payload/unix/UnixSubTlvs.java".

Comment: Oh.  I just thought of something. This is a relative path.  The actual absolute path could well be over 260 characters.

Comment: I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: Well, yeah, but now it's interesting that using NIO Files to create it doesn't even fail.

Comment: Please try and ONLY use the new API; those conversions between `File` and `Path` make things all the more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 2015 and you say that you use Java 7.

[Don't use `File`](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). Use this instead:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("....").toAbsolutePath();

// use Files.exists(path.getParent()) to check for the existence;
// if it doesn't exist use Files.createDirectories() on it
Files.createFile(thePath);
```

If the operation fails, you will at least get a *meaningful exception* telling you why it fails.

This is 2015. Drop. `File`. Now.

Comment: Ok, well, completely dropping "File" at this point is impossible, but it is useful to see what Paths/Files gives me, but my results add more confusion.  I'm adding an update.

Comment: No error at all? Huh. Now that is quite strange. Note that you can just use `.toPath()` on a `File` to create a `Path` out of it. Not that I think the results will differ but can you try with it too?

Comment: I get weird behavior if I do NOT first convert the file to an absolute path like I did in the update. I'll add more info.